# Why does 1 is printed before 4 in this execution of js code?

Tags: javascript, execution, event-loop, task-queue

```
async function check() {
  await Promise.resolve(console.log(1));
  console.log(2);
}
console.log(3);
check();
console.log(4);
```

The answer is 3,1,4,2

As I know the async function will go to web API to resolve and main program will execute first so I thought
the output will be 3, 4 , 1 , 2 but that's wrong.

Can anyone explain this in terms of event loop and micro task queue how the correct answer is executed.

Comment: `console.log(1)` is an argument to the `Promise.resolve()` expression and is therefore evaluated before the promise is even created.

Answer (score 0):

The event loop runs synchronous code first and then the asynchronous. So if you changed your function to `await Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(1))`  then the output will be 3,4,1,2